# Find most popular combinations

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe and I will like to get the combinations with highest document count.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/final.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ["topic_lda", "topic_nmf", "document_count"]
df.sort_values("document_count", ascending=False)
```

I will like to get the results like this...

```
Expected output:
    1 0 4761
    4 1 2715
    3 4 2352
    0 3 1004
    2 2 770
```

> combinations 4-0, 0-0, 3-0 are omitted because 0 is already taken
>
> combination 1-2 is omitted because 1 is already taken.

Rest of the records are not needed because there are 0 to 4 topics.

Comment: Can you explain this logic a bit more? `combinations 4-0, 0-0, 3-0 are omitted because 0 is already taken`, `combination 1-2 is omitted because 1 is already taken.`

Comment: The first row is 1-0-4761 and it means lda ID 1 is linked to nmf ID 0 and therefore I do not need those 4 records.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#first filter by topic_nmf and then by topic_lda columns
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('topic_nmf').drop_duplicates(['topic_lda'])
print (df1)
    topic_lda  topic_nmf  document_count
5           1          0            4761
21          4          1            2715
19          3          4            2352
3           0          3            1004

#filter not matched rows by topic_lda and remove duplicates
df2 = df[~(df['topic_lda'].isin(df1['topic_lda']))].drop_duplicates(['topic_lda'])
print (df2)
    topic_lda  topic_nmf  document_count
12          2          2             770

#join together
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print (df3)
    topic_lda  topic_nmf  document_count
5           1          0            4761
21          4          1            2715
19          3          4            2352
3           0          3            1004
12          2          2             770
```

Comment: There is 0-0-1986 in your output but it should be 0-3-1004 because nmf 0 is already linked to lda 1 at the first row.